# How to integrate magento with code sniffer?

Tags: php, magento

i want to integrate magento with codesniffer.i tried a lot but did't get any solution can anybody help me How to integrate magento with code sniffer

Answer (score 0):

Check The following steps it works for me http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/integrate-php-code-sniffer-and-php-mess-detector-phpstorm-magento-projects